# Chat reply notifications not getting cleared once dismissed, keeps pinging over and over again

Tags: bug, chat, notifications

Running on Chrome stable, the chat notifications seems to be pinging me repeatedly, despite having cleared them all.

Example:

[image]

and then few minutes later, they pop up again

[image]

(and yes, yes I *have* <s>turned it off and on again</s> cleared the cache and refreshed, the barrage of notifications keeps striking.)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Does "repeatedly" mean "over and over again"? I'm asking because precisely at the time in your screenshots there was a build (and there's a known issue with possible double-pings after a build).

Comment: @balpha yes, repeatedly means over and over again, at a roughly 2 minute interval.

Comment: @balpha: Just happened to me in TL. I got pinged a total of three times for a pair of messages.