# Intermittently cannot dismiss chat ping notification

Tags: bug, chat, ping

I often am in chat to be reachable by users and other moderators.

Sometimes I happen to receive a ping while I am online.

For the past few months it often happens that I cannot dismiss the notification (i.e. the "1" on the top right corner of my avatar located on the bottom left corner of the screen) by clicking on it as usual, but I first have to reload the page.

The only alternative is to post a reply that will automatically dismiss the notification, but I don't always have a reply to give (or is not needed).

I have tried to observe if I could identify any specific pattern, but I cannot see any relationship with how long the chat tab has been open, or how many chat rooms I currently am in, or anything else.

I have some browser extensions (using the latest Firefox b.t.w.), but [NoScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) is not active while navigating chat, and in general I have not added any extensions to my usual set (ABP, Ghostery, [Privacy Badger](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/privacy-badger17/), and Containers) recently.

Comment: Related? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141858/chat-reply-notifications-not-getting-cleared-once-dismissed-keeps-pinging-over

Comment: @ShadowWizard maybe, but on my side the behaviour is different. The user there can clear the notifications, I can't without reloading the page.

Comment: Yeah, that's why not a dupe. For me pings appear out of nowhere sometimes, minutes after being dismissed, but getting dozens of pings every day and not seeing any way to reproduce it, I never bothered too much tracking it down. :/